# how to get values in multiple wildcard in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

i am making a web application in codeigniter. I have a route,

```
$route['url/resp/(:num)/(:num)/(:num)'] = "url/respo/$1/$1/$1";
```

when i send `url/resp/1/598/5` it hits,

```
public function respo($item_id)
        {
            print_r($item_id);
        }
```

and all i get is 1 ie. the first value which I sent in URL and not the second and third ones.

how should I catch second and third ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was doing a mistake by catching `"url/respo/$1/$1/$1"`. Actual one is `"url/respo/$1/$2/$3"`

Answer (score 0):

**Do something like this :**

```
public function respo($item_id1, $item_id2, $item_id3)
{
   echo $item_id1;
   echo $item_id2;
   echo $item_id3;
 }
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passing-uri-segments-to-your-methods

Comment: every item_id is coming out as 1 ie. item_id1=1, item_id2=1, item_id3=1

Comment: this is working fine here i have done, tested it so many time,

Comment: did my answer helps you?